# combining cakephp's auth with hybridauth (oauth)

Tags: php, session, cakephp, oauth, hybridauth

I suppose I'm just looking for a bit of guidance as to how to set up my User + Authentication area on my website with cakephp 2.0.

I have a basic login and register functionality set up within my UserController.php, which also contains functions for looking up and displaying other users.

I also want to use the hybridauth plugin to allow for users to login/register using their social media / oauth account (allowing for more than one social account per user in the database, so that the same user could use either their twitter or facebook details, for example). I'm only having 3 providers at this time, so I plan to just create 6 columns in my user database, with the token and outhid in the same user row. This is in another controller - HybridauthController.php.

I have the hybridauth set up so that it creates its 'hybridauth' object from the account details, which is fine - but I want to be able to merge the whole 'authentication' together, so that my cakephp session contains the hybridauth session data (object) creating my general "current user" array that I can use, and set some generic variables within, depending on whether they are from oauth or not.

I don't currently store sessions in a database, and ideally I would like for allow persistent sessions for all, whether they use an oauth account or not. I don't really understand how persistent sessions are supposed to work with hybridauth, because how in this example would the $current_user_id be filled in when the user returns the next day? Not via a cookie, surely?

http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/HybridAuth_Sessions.html

So in summary I'm looking for a simple solution to combine all of my 'session' / 'auth' / 'user' data into one simple array in the users session. Hopefully that all makes sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Late to answer, but hopefully it'll help you or someone else searching.

I had a tough time integrating HybridAuth into a preexisting CakePHP (1.3) app that was already using Cake Sessions and the Auth component.  I initially tried using the Cake example that I downloaded from the HybridAuth website, but that did not work for me.

Our preexisting User controller already had a bunch of logic in it including a `beforeFilter` method.  That's where I inserted my `session_start()` as opposed to above the class declaration in the HybridAuth Cake example:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    ...
    var $components = array('Session','Auth','Email');
    ...
    public function beforeFilter(){
        // following two lines may not be necessary for your setup
        $this->Auth->allow('oauth', 'oauthLogout');
        $excludeBeforeFilter = array('oauth', 'oauthLogout');
        if ( ! in_array($this->action, $excludeBeforeFilter) ) {
            // preexisting Auth logic -- I had to bypass it because
            // calling `session_start` was messing up Cake's Auth
            ...
        } else {
            /* THIS IS NECCESSARY FOR HYBRIDAUTH (OAUTH) */
            /* setting the session ID made it so users could NOT log
               in from a 3rd party and our site */
            session_id($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP']);
            session_start();
        }
    }

    ...

    public function oauth($provider){
        $this->autoRender = false;
        // include HybridAuth
        require_once( WWW_ROOT . 'hybridauth/Hybrid/Auth.php' );

        try {
            // I stored my provider config in a Cake config file
            // It's essentially a copy from the site/Cake example
            $hybridAuth  = new Hybrid_Auth(Configure::read('HAuth.config'));
            $adapter     = $hybridAuth->authenticate($provider);
            $userProfile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

            // method on the User model to find or create the 3rd party user
            $user        = $this->User->findOrCreate($userProfile, $provider);

            if ( ! $user ) {
                echo 'Unable to find/create user';
            } else {
                // configure your fields as necessary
                $this->Auth->fields = array(...);
                $this->Auth->login($user);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

At this point the 3rd party (HybridAuth) user is accessible in the Auth Component.  This way a user was only logged in one 3rd party service or the preexisting login (but not both).

I also had an issue logging out.  To do that I basically destroyed all sessions/cookies to be safe.  In the `oauthLogout` method of the `UsersController`:

```
// probably overkill/paranoia
$this->Auth->logout();
$this->Session->destroy();
session_destroy($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP']);
/* these two seemed to make the difference 
   especially the 4th parameter */
setcookie( 'PHPSESSID', '', 1, '/' ); 
setcookie( 'CAKEPHP', '', 1, '/' );
```

Seems super hacky -- sorry for that.  Hope it helps though!